# SMART error (CurrentPendingSector) and (OfflineUncorrectableSector)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, drive, smart

I have been receiving the following error messages every day for several months now, and I do not know how to stop receiving these messages.

`CurrentPendingSector`

```
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  myhost
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 6 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors

Device info:
KingFast, S/N:03112222C0002, FW:U0803A0, 256 GB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
The original message about this issue was sent at Fri Feb  3 19:41:29 2023 PST
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

`OfflineUncorrectableSector`

```
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  myhost
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Offline uncorrectable sectors

Device info:
KingFast, S/N:03112222C0002, FW:U0803A0, 256 GB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
The original message about this issue was sent at Fri Feb  3 19:41:29 2023 PST
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

`smartctl -a /dev/sda`

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.19.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KingFast
Serial Number:    03112222C0002
Firmware Version: U0803A0
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jul  8 15:44:59 2023 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3335
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       440
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       86
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       26
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       79004
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       481
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       114
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       5050
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       98
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       88
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       35
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       86
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       168900
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       815543
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       191939

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3329         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3325         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3321         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3313         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3309         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3306         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3250         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3232         -
# 9  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3229         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       976         -
#11  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       968         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

I have tried to ignore the `197` and `198` errors in `/etc/smartd.conf` with

```
/dev/sda -d removable -n standby -H -l error -l selftest -f -t -I 197 -I 198 -s (S/../.././(01|09|17)|L/../../3/11) -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

to no avail.

I also do not see any `LBA_of_first_error` in the self-test section.

To me, it appears that `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`  is healthy and the self-tests return no errors. My current understanding is that the disk appears to be healthy but is still sending these messages erroneously.

Is there something that I'm missing?

The `/dev/sda` drive is a KingFast 256 GB SSD, and I'm not sure if this would be relevant as I could not find anything online for this particular drive or manufacturer.

How would I be able to stop receiving these messages but still have SMART monitoring for other genuine issues on the drive, and how would I fix the issue if this error message really does indicate some problem with the drive?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I have also run the following which I believe indicate that there are no errors with the drive:

```
badblocks -sv /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 250059095
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=64K conv=noerror
3907173+1 records in
3907173+1 records out
256060514304 bytes (256 GB, 238 GiB) copied, 485.648 s, 527 MB/s
```

Comment: have you restarted smartd after doing changes in "/etc/smartd.conf"?

Comment: I'd consider anything from SMART to be an indication of "Time to swap out that hardware". Losing any personal data is not fun. A 250-ish MB M.2 SSD is 20 €/$, slightly more for a 2.5" version. Up that sum slightly for four times the space.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted smartd after doing the changes in `/etc/smartd.conf`. I believe that the device actually has no problems but is sending me the error report erroneously. I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct from the information I've seen, but I don't understand what could be causing this issue.

Comment: The smart self-tests have all completed without error, both the short and extended offline tests, so I assume that there is no physical problem with the disk at all and this is some bug.

Comment: I have also run `badblocks` on `/dev/sda`: ```badblocks -sv /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 250059095
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to suppress the messages by adding `-C 197+ -U 198+`.
I think the issue is with my particular brand of SSD.